# What is the max deviation between the number of integers less than n and evenly divisible by 7 and not 2, 3 and 5 and $f7(n) = (1/2)(2/3)(4/5)(n/7)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The function $f7(n) = (1/2)(2/3)(4/5)(n/7)$ is an approximation for the number of integers that are less than or equal to $n$ and are evenly divisible by $7$ and not divisible by a prime number less than $7$.

For example, for $n=100$, there are $4$ integers less than $100$ that are evenly divisible by $7$ and not divisible by $2, 3$ and $5$. Those are $7, 49, 77$ and $91$.

The value of $f7(100)$ is 3.81 which is a close approximation to 4.

$f7(100) =  (1/2)(2/3)(4/5)(100/7) = 3.81$

I am trying to find the maximum deviation between $f7(n)$ and the actual number of integers evenly divisible by $7$ and not $2, 3$ and $5$ without empirically plugging numbers into $f7(n)$.

Looking at each of the parts of $f7(n)$, I conclude that

$n/7$ is an approximation for the number of integers evenly divisible by 7 and this approximation is off by at most $(6/7)$.

$n(4/5)$ is an approximation for the number of integers not evenly divisible by 5 and this approximation is off by at most $(4/5)$.

$n(2/3)$ is an approximation for the number of integers not evenly divisible by 3 and this approximation is off by at most $(2/3)$.

$n(1/2)$ is an approximation for the number of integers not evenly divisible by 2 and this approximation is off by at most $(1/2)$.

Summing up all these values gives $(1/2) + (2/3) + (4/5) + (6/7) = 2.824$.

Prove that the maximum deviation between $f7(n)$ and the actual number of integers evenly divisible by $7$ and not $2, 3$ and $5$ is less than $(1/2) + (2/3) + (4/5) + (6/7)$.

Comment: It might be interesting to look at how the maximum deviation varies (and where it occurs) for similar questions; ie counting and approximating the number of multiples of primes $p_1,p_2,\ldots$ that are not also multiples of primes $q_1,q_2,\ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $f_7(n)=\frac12 \frac23 \frac45 \frac{n}{7} = \frac{4n}{105}$.

Define $g(n)$ to be the count of numbers less than or equal to $n$ that are divisible by $7$ but not by any of $2$, $3$, or $5$. We want to see how well $f_7(n)$ approximates this.

We can get an exact formula for this (see below), but the key observation here is that
$$f_7(n+210)-f_7(n)=g(n+210)-g(n)=8$$
for all $n$. This is easy to see for $f_7$; intuitively, it makes sense for $g$ as well, because the additional numbers counted in the range are precisely those congruent to $\{7,49,77,91,119,133,161,203\}$ modulo $210$.

This means that both the maximum and minimum values of $f_7(n)-g(n)$ will be attained in the range $0\le n < 210$. I don't think there's a nice way to find these other than brute force; we have
$$f_7(133)-g(133)=-\frac{14}{15}\approx -0.933$$

and

$$f_7(76)-g(76)=-\frac{94}{105}\approx 0.895$$

(so the maximum deviation is in fact $\frac{14}{15}$).

---

To find a formula for $g$, we can use the inclusion-exclusion principle. We need various extra counts first.

There are $m=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{7}\right\rfloor$ positive multiples of $7$ less than or equal to $n$.

Of these, $C_2=\left\lfloor \frac{m}{2}\right\rfloor$ are also multiples of $2$; define $C_3$ and $C_5$ likewise.

Also, $C_{6}=\left\lfloor \frac{m}{6}\right\rfloor$ are multiples of $2$ and $3$; define $C_{10}$ and $C_{15}$ likewise.

Finally, $C_{30}=\left\lfloor \frac{m}{30}\right\rfloor$ are multiples of $2$, $3$ and $5$.

By inclusion-exclusion, then, the number of multiples of $7$ less than or equal to $n$ that are also multiples of at least one of $2$, $3$, or $5$ is
$$C_2+C_3+C_5-C_6-C_{10}-C_{15}+C_{30}$$

so that the number we're after (the multiples of $7$ that are *not* multiples of a smaller prime) is
$$g(n) = m-\left(C_2+C_3+C_5-C_6-C_{10}-C_{15}+C_{30}\right)$$

Since $m=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{7}\right\rfloor$, we can write $n=7m+k$ where $0\le k < 7$, so

$$g(7m+k)=m-\left\lfloor \frac{m}{2}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{m}{3}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{m}{5}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{m}{6}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{m}{10}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{m}{15}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{m}{30}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By brute force, the maximum deviation is 14/15 which is less than 2.824. Is there a way to verify that the maximum deviation is less than 2.824 without a brute force approach?